# How to handle object mapping with dynamic keys in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make the model class to handle the JSON response with dynamic keys and their values but getting an error i.e.

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'JSON:', expected 'map:')
>   Replace 'JSON' with 'map', while parsing the data to the model class.

I'm using `ObjectMapper` for a mapping JSON response

Below what I tried till now:

Top Courses Response Model to handle JSON Response Object

```
import Foundation    
import ObjectMapper

struct StudentTopCouses: Mappable {        
    init?(map: Map) {}

    var results: [String: [CoursesListObject]]?

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        results   <- map["data"]
    }
}

class CoursesListObject: Mappable {

    var id: NSNumber?
    var createdOn: NSNumber?
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var createdBy: String?
    var approved: Bool?
    var reason: String?
    var courseStatus: String?
    var courseCategory: CourseCategory?

    required init?(map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        createdOn <- map["createdOn"]
        name <- map["name"]
        description <- map["description"]
        createdBy <- map["createdBy"]
        approved <- map["approved"]
        reason <- map["reason"]
        courseStatus <- map["courseStatus"]
        courseCategory <- map["courseCategory"]
    }
}


class CourseCategory: Mappable {

var id: NSNumber?
var createdOn: NSNumber?
var category: String?
var description: Any?

required init?(map: Map){
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    createdOn <- map["createdOn"]
    category <- map["category"]
    description <- map["description"]
  }
}
```

Function for Top Courses API Success:

```
 func getTopCourseNetworkCallSuccess(data : JSON){

    if data["isSuccess"].boolValue {

        ActivityIndicator.shared.hideProgressView()

        if let r = StudentTopCouses.init(JSON: data), let result = r.results {
            for (key, value) in result {
                print("Key: \(key)" )
                print("Course Name: \(value.first!.name!)")
            }
        }   
    } else {
        //Handle Error Response
    }
}
```

Here is my API JSON Response like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "ManualTesting": [
            {
                "id": 1949,
                "createdOn": 1572433478000,
                "name": "Software Testing",
                "description": "It's a type of software Testing",
                "createdBy": "opp",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": "asdasdasdcassdqadaxasdasd",
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1916,
                    "createdOn": 1572421487000,
                    "category": "ManualTesting",
                    "description": "Ultimate QA Manual Testing course with Live project and Live demo + Real time interview questions + Life time support"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Java Technology": [
            {
                "id": 2064,
                "createdOn": 1572609103000,
                "name": "hfjfjf",
                "description": "hchcjcf\n",
                "createdBy": "Tq",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1910,
                    "createdOn": 1572346886000,
                    "category": "Java Technology",
                    "description": "Learn Java In This Course And Become a Computer Programmer. Obtain valuable Core Java Skills And Java Certification"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2159,
                "createdOn": 1572868301000,
                "name": "Spring beginner",
                "description": "we will teach you a spring boot.",
                "createdBy": "Haris",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1910,
                    "createdOn": 1572346886000,
                    "category": "Java Technology",
                    "description": "Learn Java In This Course And Become a Computer Programmer. Obtain valuable Core Java Skills And Java Certification"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2168,
                "createdOn": 1572871357000,
                "name": "Multi Threading",
                "description": "we will teach you multi threading",
                "createdBy": "Haris",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1910,
                    "createdOn": 1572346886000,
                    "category": "Java Technology",
                    "description": "Learn Java In This Course And Become a Computer Programmer. Obtain valuable Core Java Skills And Java Certification"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2169,
                "createdOn": 1572871521000,
                "name": "Hybernate ",
                "description": "we will teach you hybernate",
                "createdBy": "Haris",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1910,
                    "createdOn": 1572346886000,
                    "category": "Java Technology",
                    "description": "Learn Java In This Course And Become a Computer Programmer. Obtain valuable Core Java Skills And Java Certification"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2293,
                "createdOn": 1573032019000,
                "name": "Spring",
                "description": "we will teach you spring",
                "createdBy": "hard",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": "",
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1910,
                    "createdOn": 1572346886000,
                    "category": "Java Technology",
                    "description": "Learn Java In This Course And Become a Computer Programmer. Obtain valuable Core Java Skills And Java Certification"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Python Technology": [
            {
                "id": 2041,
                "createdOn": 1572601461000,
                "name": "Python for Data Science and Machine Learning Bootcamp",
                "description": "Learn how to use NumPy, Pandas, Seaborn , Matplotlib , Plotly , Scikit-Learn , Machine Learning, Tensorflow , and more",
                "createdBy": "DL",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1912,
                    "createdOn": 1572346929000,
                    "category": "Python Technology",
                    "description": "This Python For Beginners Course Teaches You The Python Language Fast. Includes Python Online Training With Python 3"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2043,
                "createdOn": 1572604907000,
                "name": "Learn Python Programming Masterclass",
                "description": "This Python For Beginners Course Teaches You The Python Language Fast. Includes Python Online Training With Python 3",
                "createdBy": "DL",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1912,
                    "createdOn": 1572346929000,
                    "category": "Python Technology",
                    "description": "This Python For Beginners Course Teaches You The Python Language Fast. Includes Python Online Training With Python 3"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2044,
                "createdOn": 1572604961000,
                "name": "The Python Bible™ | Everything You Need to Program in Python",
                "description": "Build 11 Projects and go from Beginner to Pro in Python with the World's Most Fun Project-Based Python Course!",
                "createdBy": "DL",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1912,
                    "createdOn": 1572346929000,
                    "category": "Python Technology",
                    "description": "This Python For Beginners Course Teaches You The Python Language Fast. Includes Python Online Training With Python 3"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2046,
                "createdOn": 1572604968000,
                "name": "The Python Bible™ | Everything You Need to Program in Python",
                "description": "Build 11 Projects and go from Beginner to Pro in Python with the World's Most Fun Project-Based Python Course!",
                "createdBy": "DL",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1912,
                    "createdOn": 1572346929000,
                    "category": "Python Technology",
                    "description": "This Python For Beginners Course Teaches You The Python Language Fast. Includes Python Online Training With Python 3"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2047,
                "createdOn": 1572604969000,
                "name": "The Python Bible™ | Everything You Need to Program in Python",
                "description": "Build 11 Projects and go from Beginner to Pro in Python with the World's Most Fun Project-Based Python Course!",
                "createdBy": "DL",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1912,
                    "createdOn": 1572346929000,
                    "category": "Python Technology",
                    "description": "This Python For Beginners Course Teaches You The Python Language Fast. Includes Python Online Training With Python 3"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2048,
                "createdOn": 1572604971000,
                "name": "The Python Bible™ | Everything You Need to Program in Python",
                "description": "Build 11 Projects and go from Beginner to Pro in Python with the World's Most Fun Project-Based Python Course!",
                "createdBy": "DL",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1912,
                    "createdOn": 1572346929000,
                    "category": "Python Technology",
                    "description": "This Python For Beginners Course Teaches You The Python Language Fast. Includes Python Online Training With Python 3"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2049,
                "createdOn": 1572604972000,
                "name": "The Python Bible™ | Everything You Need to Program in Python",
                "description": "Build 11 Projects and go from Beginner to Pro in Python with the World's Most Fun Project-Based Python Course!",
                "createdBy": "DL",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1912,
                    "createdOn": 1572346929000,
                    "category": "Python Technology",
                    "description": "This Python For Beginners Course Teaches You The Python Language Fast. Includes Python Online Training With Python 3"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Mobile App Development": [
            {
                "id": 2002,
                "createdOn": 1572528493000,
                "name": "Flutter",
                "description": "Flutter is a mobile technology",
                "createdBy": "DL",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 2001,
                    "createdOn": 1572528308000,
                    "category": "Mobile App Development",
                    "description": "Boom in market"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Automation Testing": [
            {
                "id": 1950,
                "createdOn": 1572435931000,
                "name": "Selenium",
                "description": "It's a automation testing tool for web",
                "createdBy": "opp",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": "fvgbhnj",
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1915,
                    "createdOn": 1572421405000,
                    "category": "Automation Testing",
                    "description": "\"TOP RATED (BEST SELLER) #1 Master SELENIUM java course\" -3 Million students learning worldWide with great collaboration"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2073,
                "createdOn": 1572611314000,
                "name": "string",
                "description": "string",
                "createdBy": "ski",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": null,
                "courseStatus": "APPROVED",
                "courseCategory": {
                    "id": 1915,
                    "createdOn": 1572421405000,
                    "category": "Automation Testing",
                    "description": "\"TOP RATED (BEST SELLER) #1 Master SELENIUM java course\" -3 Million students learning worldWide with great collaboration"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": "Success",
    "timestamp": 1573199357155,
    "status": 200,
    "isSuccess": true
}
```

But here I'm facing an error while parsing the JSON Response

```
if let r = StudentTopCouses.init(JSON: data), let result = r.results {
     for (key, value) in result {
         print("Key: \( key )" )
         print("Course Name: \( value.first!.name! )")
     }
}
```

Error message:

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'JSON:', expected 'map:')
>   Replace 'JSON' with 'map'

Comment: Rather than `SwiftyJSON` **and** `ObjectMapper` use `Codable`. It's built-in, efficient, easy to use and there are no dependencies. And don't use `NS..` classes in Swift if there is a native counterpart (`Int`, `Bool`). And for the dynamic type use generics, enums with associated types or a custom `init(from decoder` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the documentation: https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper

`StudentTopCouses` constructor is `init?(map: Map)` not `init(JSON: ...)`

So the error is correct on line: `let r = StudentTopCouses.init(JSON: data)` where you don't have such a constructor..

The `Mappable` protocol is as follows (as per link above in Mappable.swift):

```
public protocol Mappable: BaseMappable {
    init?(map: Map)
}
```

As per documentation above, you'd have to do:

`if let studentTopCourses = Mapper<StudentTopCourses>().map(JSONObject: SomeJSONDictionary)`

or:

`if let studentTopCourses = Mapper<StudentTopCourses>().map(JSONString: SomeJSONString)`

**EDIT:** Since you are using `SwiftyJSON` library AND `ObjectMapper` library, you need to interface both of them:

```
if let jsonString = data.rawString(), let r = Mapper<StudentTopCouses>.map(JSONString: jsonString)
```

or:

```
//Can use JSON or JSONObject here..
if let jsonDict = data.dictionaryObject(), let r = Mapper<StudentTopCouses>.map(JSON: jsonDict)
```

Comment: What to do?? Because I'm not able to handle this JSON Response. Please suggest a better way to do so.

Comment: I added an answer to that question but you honestly need to read the documentation for the library you decided to use.. Convert your data to a string or to a dictionary then use the appropriate `Mapper` function.

Comment: Is there any better way to Handle this API response. If yes, please suggest that because I am still getting the issue.

Comment: You are doing something else wrong then. As far as I can tell, you have some kind of object called `JSON`. If I make the assumption that this is `SwiftyJSON`, then you need to convert BEFORE calling ObjectMapper. Which means you need to do:  `data.dictionaryObject` or `data.rawString` then call ObjectMapper.. It seems you are using quite a few libraries and just expecting things to work :l You really need to read the error. We aren't able to guess the other errors you're getting that this answer won't solve. It definitely solves the one in your question and that's all.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks @Brandon. You are right, I'm using swiftyJSON and Object Mapper.

Comment: Added an answer for `SwiftyJSON` interfacing. Hopefully that solves all the problems. Suggestion: Maybe you can cut back on the usage of third-party libraries and just use built in Swift stuff like `Codable` or `JSONSerialization` or something

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brandon.  I'm a beginner and learning how to do codable. Could you please share some reference to do so.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types